# Get page author in CQ5

Tags: aem

Is there any way to get the current page author's email address and other profile details in CQ5 ?

I need to publish it on my page. I could make it a text-component and let the author himself add it, but it would be cool to display it from backend ..

For now, I could only get the name using `Page.LastModifiedBy()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the author's username through the [jcr:createdBy](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrConstants.html#JCR_CREATED_BY) property on the page's jcr:content node.

You can then look up email addresses through the UserManager, which you can [adaptTo from a JcrSession object](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/sling-adapters.html).  This page has some [additional information on loading user information](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4549847).

From a JSP you could do something like this:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" import="org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.*, com.day.cq.commons.jcr.*" %>
...
<%
 String createdBy = properties.get(JcrConstants.JCR_CREATED_BY, String.class);

 UserManager userManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);
 Authorizable authorizable = userManager.getAuthorizable(createdBy);
  if (authorizable.hasProperty("profile/familyName")) {
        String familyName = authorizable.getProperty("profile/familyName")[0].getString();        
  }
%>
```